# Access denied when attempting remote WMI calls from a service

Tags: c#, wmi, dcom

I have a C# application which connects via WMI to many remote systems, both in a domain and standalone.  The program provides wmi with credentials and uses impersonation.  When run manually (from a console), it connects fine and all is well.  However, when this same .exe is called from a service (running as local user), it always gets 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED) when it calls Connect() on the ManagementScope.

I've searched quite a bit and found many seemingly useful articles on similar topics, but none work.
[This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/03/13/let-s-troubleshoot-wmi-part-1-remoting-and-security.aspx) and his [subsequent post][2] on MS's site is very similar, except my failure happens at connect, not when trying to run a query, so it feels like a local system permission issue.

I have messed with DCOM permissions, WMI remoting permissions, impersonation options, policy options, windows firewall, among other things, all with no results.  Is there anyone out there who can help?

Edit: With a little more digging I found [this small page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/03/13/let-s-troubleshoot-wmi-part-1-remoting-and-security.aspx) from MS, which really points to my error (0x80070005) being a DCOM problem which happens during connection, and not specifically a WMI error.  The causes they give are 1. Credential failure, or 2. DCOM launch/Remote activation permissions.  Since my program works when run manually using the same credentials, I have to assume its a DCOM issue.  I have set Remote/Local Activation & launch to allow for SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, INTERACTIVE and Administrators, but it still fails.  Since the service is running as Local System, I assume these settings should suffice.

Comment: Did you fix this problem? Similar issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I may be oversimplifying or not fully understanding your problem, but it seems to me that if you're trying to access a *remote* WMI provider via a service having only credentials from a *machine local* account, such an effort will always fail (by design). There is no path for authentication from MACHINE\account to OTHERMACHINE\account or DOMAIN\account. Again, if I'm oversimplifying or misunderstanding, my apologies.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply.  I apologize if I didn't make my situation more clear.  The c# application does provide authentication/credentials for the remote machine and does not rely on  a domain/machine account trust.  In fact, the target computers are both in and outside the source domain.  I have also tried running this on a standalone (XP) workstation, and it fails in the same way.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: This is probably a path you've already undertaken, but I think I'd invest some time in setting up a copy of ProcMon on both the source and destination machines, fire up your service, and let ProcMon gobble up the results to see *exactly* when that failure happens. It might give you a better idea of where you need to focus the fix.